Conflict in merge request in GitLab but no conflict on local
Hello,
I created a new branch from the 'develop' branch (I pulled before to be up-to-date with GitLab), I worked on my new branch then I pushed my new branch to GitLab.
Then I created a merge request from my new branch to 'develop' on GitLab.
Now, I can see there is a conflict in my merge request with a file I didn't modify.
I tried on local to merge the 'develop' branch in my new branch or to rebase my branch from 'develop', but I get everytime the same message than everything is up-to-date, what should I do to fix the issue in GitLab please?
Thanks

I find it tricky that you get a conflict about a file you did not modify. If that were the case, and without hidden stuff going on, that should not happen because the file as you have it in your branch would be the same as it was when you started working on your branch. Now, in general, I would ask you to check that the 2 tips that you are trying to merge locally are the same that are being merged in gitlab... make sure the commit IDs of the 2 tips are the same.

I updated the file in conflict few days ago but it is already merged successfully in the 'develop' branch and because I pull before creating my branch, I should have the version from GitLab? I compared the file from local and GitLab and thex are identical, it is why I am confused.

Are you squash merging at some point?

No, I should do (from the new branch on local): git merge --squash develop ?

No no.... do not start playing games with squashing. I was asking because it might explain a little bit what you are seeing.

Well... the question stands: are you merging locally the same thing that is being merged in gitlab? Did you compare commit IDs involved already?

You mean checking if the commit Id in GitLab is also in my new branch? With "git log"? If no, what should I do to merge properly GitLab in my new branch in local? git pull origin develop?

You say that you try to do locally the same merge that gitlab is doing and you get different results, right? That obviously points to you and gitlab merging different things, right? So, check that your 2 branches tips (the commit IDs) are the same as the tips in gitlab. How to see the commits locally? git rev-parse some-branch. And in gitlab, check in the UI the last commit ID of each branch (you could also do it by fetching and then checking locally but I want to avoid getting more variables into the equation).

perhaps all you are missing is a fetch to get it all working as expected.

To resume:

I worked few days ago locally on a file 1 on the branch A (branch created from develop)
I pushed my branch A with my file 1 to Gitlab then I merged successfully my branch A into the branch develop in GitLab
Today I made a pull request on the develop branch locally (to retrieve everything from GitLab in local) then I created a new branch B from develop and I worked on the file 2
I pushed my branch B and my file 2 to GitLab then I create a merge request from my branch B to the branch develop in GitLab
Unfortunatelly, GitLab says that I have a conflict on the file A



If I try locally to merge the branch develop into my branch B, Git says everything is up-to-date
If I try locally to rebase my branch B from develop, Git says everything is up-to-date
I compared the file 1 between my local and GitLab and I have the same version (no difference)

What can I do to fix?

I will do a git fetch tomorrow at work.

Ok.... If the repo is not big, post this in the question: git log --oneline --graph A B develop master origin/A origin/B origin/develop origin/master. We might catch what is going on there

and you need to get that after fetching.... Otherwise you might show us old stuff.

I found a solution, I rebased my branch not from develop but from origin/develop:
git rebase origin/develop
then I fixed conflicts and I pushed to my new branch:
git push --force
